# How cross platform is the standard C++ library?

Tags: android, c++, ios, cross-platform, std

Is the C++ standard library (e.g. std::string stream) available on iOS and Android (using the JNI/NDK)? If so:

To what degree is it supported? 
How are desktop specific features such as the console handled?
How fast/reliable is it?
How many other mobile platforms is it available on?
Can I count on not having to modify much code using the std library when porting to mobile platforms (such as iOS)?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with those platforms, but the standard library *should* be available in all platforms for which there is a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ standard library is available on both.  Furthermore, iOS has had C++11 for quite a while.

Both platforms - fundamentally being POSIX based - have the concept of console IO, but neither provides access to it in the user interface, and on neither can you (at least out of the box) run a console application directly.

As a consequence, it's obvious that you can't use console IO for any kind of user-interaction with your application - unless that is, you build it using the platform's user-interface API.

In terms of portability, there shouldn't be any issues on either platform - it's the GNU Std G++ library on Android and the Clang C++ library on iOS.  Portability is a non-issue on iOS,  but you'll probably have fun building JNI bindings for Android.

In reality though, you're only ever able to build the back-ends of applications in C++. All user interfaces will be distinctly non portable, and will generally need to be implemented in the language of the UI framework.

Windows Phone 8 allows native Apps, and C++ seems to be the language of choice to implement them in.   BlackBerry OS 10 is fundamentally QNX under the hood, which is also POSIX compliant.

Comment: "In reality though, you're only ever able to build the back-ends of applications in C++." - You're right: I am working on a cross platform game engine and even though C++ can be compiled on many platforms I still have to write a segment of platform code for each platform I program for e.g. For iOS I am writing a bunch of Objective-C code as a wrapper for my C++.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, standard libraries *should be* standard across all platforms. Now their internal implementation may or will vary but they should perform the task for which they were introduced.

Generally std lib is very efficient, fast and well tested so it should be reliable.

The actual catch is that std lib should be included with C++ implementation but it is totally upto the vendor implementing C++ whether std lib included or not.
Even if they don't include std lib there is a high chance that you can find alternative implementation for that platform. Then all you have to do is link that library with your code.

Assuming that there is a C++ compiler supporting major features.

Even if that is not possible, you can always port the required std functions to that specific platform as a custom lib.

Hope this helps,